# C (Dynamic) Array (Fixed size)

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, stack, push

Hello I am wondering why this works since on tutorials and such it always lists that arrays must be of fixed size except when dynamically making one with malloc.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        if(argc < 2)
        return 0;

        int tmp[ atoi(argv[1])  ];


        printf("sizeof tmp equals to %d\n", sizeof tmp);
        return 0;
}
```

What happens in the background at ASM-level when doing this? And how does it work?
Does it allocate the size given at starting the program on the stack and what's the max for the stack?

Also is this more memory expensive than using malloc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a C99 feature called a [variable length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: At the assembler level, something like adjusting the stack pointer by a variable value should do it. It's probably done at the entrance to a block. The maximum is system dependent, there is no portable way to know in advance if this will succeed. If you use a length of 0 or less, the behaviour is undefined. It's usually way cheaper than `malloc` in terms of time and probably slightly cheaper in terms of space (you usually have more heap memory than stack memory available). Related: GNU `alloca`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C99 introduces [variable length array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) whose length is not a constant expression. The declaration

```
int tmp[ atoi(argv[1]) ];
```

declares `tmp` as VLA.